# How do I use SNMP to monitor job status on a printer?

Tags: snmp

I've been trying to figure out how to monitor job status via SNMP and I have found a solution on Xerox based printers (using Xerox implemented mibs), but I'm looking for something that will work across other vendors' printers. I see the Job Monitoring rfc2707 looks like the proper mib to be using but it doesn't appear that many printers implement it. Does anyone know of another way to query a printer via snmp to get a job status back from a printer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trick is to query each printer's management MIB, determine which enterprise MIB it supports (via the OID variable [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.html) ), and then query according to that (by changing which enterprise MIB variables you query).

From the OID description:

```
                  "The vendor's authoritative identification of the
                  network management subsystem contained in the
                  entity.  This value is allocated within the SMI
                  enterprises subtree (1.3.6.1.4.1) and provides an
                  easy and unambiguous means for determining `what
                  kind of box' is being managed.  For example, if
                  vendor `Flintstones, Inc.' was assigned the
                  subtree 1.3.6.1.4.1.4242, it could assign the
                  identifier 1.3.6.1.4.1.4242.1.1 to its `Fred
                  Router'."
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about this over a year ago, but I too am now in the process of setting up job monitoring. I too found the Job Monitoring rfc2707 and also found its lack of implementation. I have since come to the conclusion that each printer (or at least manafacturer) is going to have its own way of doing it. The current printer I need to connect to is a xerox, and I can obtain the printer status, and the status information for the jobs, but I can not find a way of getting the job name. (For some reason xerox seem to have implemented this by using a look up from the job information to a string table) My issue is the string table always appears empty. I require the job name to be able to map a job in my applications print queue to the job in the printer. I saw in your post you said you have a solution or at least found a solution for xerox printers and was wondering if your solution included getting the job name, if so would you be able to share an example with me?

Comment: To get around this issue we ended up overwriting the user field with a unique id, that way we can always find our job in the snmp table.