# c# get page count for all printers with snmp

Tags: c#, snmp, mib, oid

I have a c# program that need to take the black, color, scan page counts (the total).

I'm using at the moment SNMP with OID to get it but it is very difficult becuase each printer has its own OID. The problem is that each printer has its own MIB numbers to get the black,color,scan page counts.

I'm looking for a generic solution that will work on most (if not all).
Any thoughts and examples on how do I do that?

Comment: Did you get the solution? I am also trying to find this for one of my project..

Comment: Try looking into these:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008945/how-do-i-use-snmp-to-monitor-job-status-on-a-printer/
and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440106/snmpget-command-to-retrieve-printer-location
The first one deals with how to find out the correct MIB to use, and the second one will tell you how to find the number of printed pages.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655567/how-to-find-counters-of-printers-through-snmp
Search before you ask!